# Join two files based on matching of columns with some error

Tags: awk

I have two files, both different number of lines. The files goes as

```
file1
0.156667 152.063604 17730.697726 
100.256071 211.932169 14827.664042 
108.604047 88.095015 12687.034619 
11.868409 263.975480 16270.787931 
126.014430 19.739961 19800.463965 

file2
100.808    211.717    14.55     6002.643     16072.78     
109.480     89.050     8.21     6002.197     8962.211     
12.524    263.842    13.07     6001.377     11975.58     
126.885     20.086    10.30     6002.365     16113.52
```

The input I want is

```
0.156667 152.063604 17730.697726 NA NA NA
100.256071 211.932169 14827.664042 14.55     6002.643     16072.78 
108.604047 88.095015 12687.034619 8.21     6002.197     8962.211
11.868409 263.975480 16270.787931 13.07     6001.377     11975.58  
126.014430 19.739961 19800.463965 10.30     6002.365     16113.52
```

Hence I want to match the fist two columns within an error of +- 2. And based on that, where the match is positive, I need to attach columns $3,$4 and $5 from the second file into the first one (or create a new file). In the case there's no match, I should get NA.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it with `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1,$2]=$3 FS $4 FS $5; 
    next
}
{
    for(x in a) {
        split(x,t,SUBSEP);  
        if(t[1]-2<=$1 && $1<=t[1]+2 && t[2]-2<=$2 && $2<=t[2]+2) {
            print $0, a[x]
            next
        }
    }
    print $0, "NA NA NA"
}' file2 file1
0.156667 152.063604 17730.697726 NA NA NA
100.256071 211.932169 14827.664042 14.55 6002.643 16072.78
108.604047 88.095015 12687.034619 8.21 6002.197 8962.211
11.868409 263.975480 16270.787931 13.07 6001.377 11975.58
126.014430 19.739961 19800.463965 10.30 6002.365 16113.52
```

Comment: Why are you using `int()`?

Comment: @glennjackman Due to the decimals. I thought of stipping them off before comparison, but I think you are right. They don't seem to offer much.

Comment: You seem to be adding a requirement that was not asked for.

Comment: @glennjackman You're right. Updated the answer to remove superfluous `int()` usage.